# Format value from EF property?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, formatting

If I have a value stored in a column in the db, and use EF to get it, is there a recommended way to formatting it when retrieving it?

For example, I store 6 digits in a string "123456", and every time the value is retrieved, it should be returned as "12˚34'56".

When stored, it should just be the digits again.

Currently, I'm doing it straight in the linq-query, but I'm not sure that is the best way. I do not want to change anything in the db.

Comment: This can be done with NHibernate and a Custom User Type. :) Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF doesn't have any formatting options. That is task for your application logic. So either add custom non mapped property to your entity and let it return formatted value from mapped integer property or use custom query projection as you probably do at the moment.

Comment: Is it "Complex Property" that could be used for that?

Comment: No complex property is not solution for that. Complex property just exposes complex type which has same limitations as entity.